# Fraudulent ex colleague hired at current employer

Tags: human-resources, ethics, fraud

I've recently learned of a former colleague being hired at my current employer. From multiple sources news came to me regarding his termination. This was due to fraud and he was subsequently fired on the spot.

Should I notify my employer?

Comment: Unless he faced criminal charges leave it alone.

Comment: thank you for your reply. To clarify: he did not face criminal charges

Comment: One question: How do you know about the reason he was fired?

Comment: Two former colleagues I keep in touch with individually shared the story.

Answer (score 9):

> Should I notify my employer?

If you have some reason for maliciously trying to sabotage his new job you could pass on hearsay or even find proof and hand that in.

In theory though the employer should already be aware or they didn't do their homework properly. People do get hired despite being fired elsewhere for fraud, in some locales I've seen whole careers where a person has been forced out of multiple jobs for outright theft and still got another job, even in finance positions.

Depending on the position, your role, and locale you have no ethical or professional responsibility to do anything about this. You're obviously not part of the hiring process.

Comment: Don't assume I'm malicious ;) There's a chance I will have to work with this person on the same project, so besides any possible ethical concerns there are practical concerns. I've done some further inquiries into his current/new position and I already know he has made certain claims about his abilities. Abilities I have verified he does not have. I'm concerned that at some point people with ask me about 'what's the deal with this guy"

Comment: Why would they ask you? Did you refer him?

Comment: to whom do you refer with 'they'?

Comment: no idea, you're the one saying people with you ask about him

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. What I meant was they know I've worked with him. Thus if he turns out to be not quite as competent and/or fraudulent people might ask me about our previous working relationship. I know this is a hypothetical.

Comment: that would be the time to mention he hasn't got a great rep, no one can blame you for not mentioning anything earlier it's all second hand information

Comment: I'll keep that in mind Kilisi

Answer (score -2):

> This was due to fraud and he was subsequently fired on the spot.

Do you have any contact which can *reliably* verify the story here? If yes: The specifics of the action depend on:

- your companies procedures
- the position he is going to have
- your current responsibility
- your relationship to your direct boss
- the reliability of the HR department to keep confidential things confidential
- probation time rules (if he was just hired it could be easier to fire him now)
- the importance of compliance in your company

I think my reaction would be between the following possibilities:

- If the company is well run, i would imagine that you could write to HR something like: It came to my attention that you plan to hire Mr. X. I happen to know Mr/Mrs. Y. which would be willing to add something to your picture here.
- If the HR department doesn't care, and you have a good relationship with your direct boss, and he is open to information, the address the same to him/her.
- If you have the feeling that nobody cares or that the company/department even appreciates employees with a certain moral flexibility, then say nothing (and run).

Comment: I would be a bit more strict and only proceed if the actual act of fraud can be strongly verified. Even if the person was fired for a cause, it may turn out that the actual act did not occur.